# Emacs graphics glitch on OS X Terminal

Tags: emacs

I randomly see some graphics glitch on Emacs on OS X Terminal.
Here's what I see while pushing space bar.

[image]

And here's what actually saved. (I checked this by c-x, c-c and reloading the file)

[image]

Why this happen and how to fix this?

**Update**

Here's some additional descriptions to @lunaryorn's advise.

1. This is randomly reproducible. (for different keystroke, but it eventually happens, mostly for each session),
2. I installed Emacs using Homebrew (`brew install emacs`)
3. I want Unix experience instead of Mac experience. I am trying Emacs to learn as an universally available editor on any Unix environment, not Mac specific usage.

Comment: Is this issue reproducible, i.e. does it happen any time you're using Emacs in terminal?  How did you install Emacs?  And last, why aren't you using a graphical Emacs?

Comment: Oh dear… a GUI Emacs is not less “Unix experience” than a terminal Emacs.  After all, it's **Emacs**, in either of these cases.  You will be able to use it **exactly the same way**, except that the GUI is much nicer, because it has more display and editing capabilities, including fringe icons, full RGB colors (= fancier color themes), clipboard access, modifier re-mapping, etc…  The latter is especially nice on OS X, because you can re-map Alt to Command, which is easier to reach while typing.

Comment: @lunaryorn Thanks for advising. I can agree GUI Emacs would be pretty same. But anyway, my main goal is having an ability to work on complete CUI environment (in other words completely mouse-less, windows-less), and Emacs is just a tool for it. So using GUI Emacs is somewhat out of my goal :P